# How to Import FileReference and FileSystemTree to ActionScript

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, msxml

I tried to insert a FileSystemTree in Flex .
Flash Builder doesn't recognise that and produces the error:

```
1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: FileSystemTree
```

Here's the code . It's a very basic one ....

```
<mx:HDividedBox width="100%" height="725" paddingLeft="10" paddingRight="10" paddingBottom="10" paddingTop="10" y="41">
    <mx:VBox width="200" height="100%">
        <mx:FileSystemTree id="fileSystemTree" width="100%" height="100%" change="onChange(event)" />
    </mx:VBox>
    <mx:Canvas width="100%" height="100%" id="content" ></mx:Canvas>
</mx:HDividedBox>
```

I'm using Flex 4 , Flash Builder 4. What am i doing wrong ? Is FileSystemTree supported in Flex 4 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That component is only available within Adobe AIR applications, not browser-based Flex applications, since browsing the local file system would violate the browser sandbox.

EDIT: Now that I understand your intention, yes, you can upload files from a flex application without having to use AIR.  Instead of using the FileSystemTree component (which is AIR only), you use FileReference.browse() to allow the user to select a file from the local filesystem to upload.  This page from the documentation will give you all the info you need: [Working with file upload and download](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=17_Networking_and_communications_7.html)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you Mueller , so there is no way to upload file from computer from flex ?

Comment: Hi vettipayyan, I edited my answer, let me know if you still have questions.  Good luck.

Comment: Thank you again Mueller... I've looked the diff bw air and flex after you said about AIR apps . I thought AIR will suit my app.So i'm now writing the app in AIR.Running smoothly...